# Computing the stochastic complexity with $\Theta=\{0,1,\frac{1}{2}\}$

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

[image]

> Let $\Theta = \{0,1,\frac{1}{2}\}$, show that for all $m \geq 1$
> $S_{m,\Theta} = \ln (3-2^{-m+1})$.

In the previous question was asked to show that  when $\Theta = \{1\}$ that for all $m \geq 1$ $S_{m,\Theta} = 1$. I've managed to do that by computing

$S_{m,\Theta} = \ln(\sum_{i=0}^m \Big( \frac{1}{3}\Big)^{i}*\Big( \frac{2}{3}\Big)^{m-i}\binom{m}{i})=0$.

For the second part I computed, $p_{0} (z^m)=p_{1}(z^m)= 2^m$ and $p_{\frac{1}{2}}(z_m)=1$. I'm not seeing how I could combine these three in to the asked $3-2^{-m+1}$.

Any tips on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!